# How to prove this set equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having problems proving this set equivalence (discrete mathematics)

```
 B∩~(~B∩~B)=B
```

I've used double negation, de morgans and then the associative law but I can't quite get there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

De Morgan's is not needed here - just the fact that the intersection of a set with itself is itself and that the negation of a set's negation is the set itself.

```
  B ∩ ~(~B ∩ ~B)
= B ∩ ~(~B)          S ∩ S = S
= B ∩ B              ~(~S) = S
= B                  S ∩ S = S
```

If you are working with a set of axioms where these rules are not included, I suggest deriving those first.